# Swap Stylesheet OnClick For Demo Page

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

My level of JavaScript experience is minimal. I have searched this site and the web for answers to my problem and found lots of them. I have cut-and-pasted then tested solutions but none work for me. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

I picked up this code here but clicking buttons makes no changes. Doesn't even set the wait cursor spinning as if it's thinking about it. (The test style sheet angelfish only attempts to change `h2` color, for now.) Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have a real need to do this on my site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      id="original"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cyndikirkpatrick.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/ctc-style.css"
    />
  </head>
  <script>
    $('#original').click(function() {
      $('link[href="https://cyndikirkpatrick.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/ctc-style.css"]').attr(
        'href',
        'style1.css'
      );
    });
    $('#angelfish').click(function() {
      $('link[href="https://cyndikirkpatrick.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/angelfish.css"]').attr(
        'href',
        'style2.css'
      );
    });
  </script>
  <body>
    <h2>Javascript Change StyleSheet Without Page Reload</h2>
    <button id="original">Original</button><br />
    <button id="angelfish">Angelfish</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://cyndikirkpatrick.com/test/

My end goal: One page that can switch styles for each texture set in my library, to produce a simplified version of this page:
https://cyndikirkpatrick.com/angelfish-texture-tiles-teal/

Comment: On your site you have an JavaScript error. Try fixing that first.

Comment: Easier way for what you want might be loading both and just changing class/id. For example, style one will be everything nested in .style1 class. When you click to change, on root element (body or some div) you change it to .style2 class. Like that, you wont need to wait for style to be loaded. If stylesheets are not too large ofc.

Comment: This may be easier to do on the server-side.

Comment: I have 100 demo pages but Google hates that because it sees them as duplicates so, ultimately, I need to let visitors choose a texture set to see in use on a single page. Only colors and background images change but there are a lot of them per page.I fear if I make it one long style sheet, it will be too long to load? I hope that if I get a handle of the basic process, I can tinker to perfect it for my use but I'm pretty lost right now.

This is my first attempt to use JavaScript for anything so it must be a plug-in. I will try to track that down.

Comment: I "fixed" the error which turned out to be an invisible end paragraph right after the script start. With it gone, now it says "$ is not a function" and stops loading the page. I'm so sorry to be so dense. I've been at this for days and just keep making it worse, I fear.

Comment: I'm on my own now, aren't I? I'm sorry. I think my understanding of JavaScript is too shallow for partial snippets to help. Thanks to all for trying, though.

Answer (score 0):

Style are not dynamically reset and reloaded if you modify the href.
You can however delete the style and append a new one in the body.

```
// Remove
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet]');
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}

// Add
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.id   = cssId;
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet.css';
link.media = 'all';
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Small note: this will delete ALL stylesheets, you can change the selector to target specific stylesheets

Comment: I have one hundred style sheets (or at least 100 different page styles that change colors and background images on divs). Would this be appropriate for that?

Comment: Thanks, Bastian. I posted this in the head of the page and yes, it definitely removes the styling. I don't quite understand how I link the HTML buttons to the new style sheets, though.

Comment: Also, I don't want to remove parent style sheets, exactly. I want to overwrite selected portions of them.

Answer (score 0):

I just dropped back to mention the solution I used, for the moment. I think it's closest to Chris' suggestion. I'm making a function for each texture tile, then displaying them onclick in a "Demonstration Swatch" area. A visitor gets to see what the tiles look like as a repeating background.

I did it that way because research mainly provided examples of people changing one element. I watched quite a few videos, then cobbled together bits of code from W3school.

I am fairly sure I am doing this in the most awkward and repetitive way imaginable but I hope to make the code elegant as my understanding of JavaScript grows. For now, it works and serves its purpose.

Thanks again to all.

https://cyndikirkpatrick.com/texture-tiles/gray-texture-sets/